# Convert x y to long lat

Tags: python, geolocation, latitude-longitude

I have a set of (x,y) where all points creates a map. Some points (1/7 of the data) in that has long and lat like this (x,y,long_x,lat_y).

Cana Sect:( 60.682697   35.01935    -66.230895     18.346775)

Is there anyway I can get the long and lat of all points based on x and y? Does pyproj allow reverse long lat conversion like this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yes, `proj` can convert in any direction. Of course you need to know which coordinate reference system is used.